# struts2 textarea add style to only one word

Tags: javascript, html, css, struts2, stylesheet

I have struts 2 `<s:textarea>` setting value dynamically using JavaScript. In my JavaScript I am constructing a single String using an array of Strings, in that I want to show some dynamic feature to the updated array index.

How to add style to the specific array index before constructing single string. So that when I set the constructed String as,

```
strarray[2]=strarray[2].bold();
styleString=strarray.join('|');
document.forms[0]["updatedtxtArea"].value=styleString;
```

it will bold the single array index only, In my Textarea, it shows like ...welcome to `<b>value of (strarray[2])</b>`  I want to see the bold result but it shows html stuff itself?? I want to replace the `<b>` to real feel like **value of(strarray[2])**. How to make this true? is there any alternate way... anyway I want to do it. please....

Comment: go with some html-editor, tinymce or something.

Comment: i am a newbie, how to use this Editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea`s only accept string input, you can't add styling like you would in HTML.

A solution is to switch to `contenteditable` but that's quite a can of worms in and of itself.

Comment: can't use replace method with regex? previously, I replace \n character with "\n" it printed newline within textarea...

Comment: it has nothing with styling, do you mean CSS with HTML? No, it's wrong.

Comment: @nikpon I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Could you elaborate, because it has no any meaning with opposed to OP's requirement.

Comment: Wouldnt normally vote but thought the -1 was undeserved. Answer makes sense... or going with a full blown editor solution such as any of the ones from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84353/i-need-a-wysiwyg-web-editor-web-based

Comment: Thanks, and yes, the wysiwyg editors have the same approach `contenteditable` has but they're quite the can of worms too.